# How to move a sprite along a CGPath with variable velocity

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am programming a game and want to move a sprite along a fixed path (straights and curves - think railroad engine) but I want to be able to drive the animation in terms of the sprites velocity - and change that velocity in response to game events.

followPath:duration: in SKAction is close, but there seems no way to adjust the speed "on the fly" - I definitely care about sprite speed - not 'duration to follow path'.

CGPath seems like the right construct for defining the path for the sprite, but there doesn't seem to be enough functionality there to grab points along the path and do my own math.

Can anyone suggest a suitable approach?

Comment: refer to this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-airplane-game-with-sprite-kit-enemies-emitters--mobile-19916

Comment: thanks @Revinder, but that seems to use followPath in the way I described, which does not allow for changing the speed over time.

Comment: @JustinHawkins, have you found the solution? The same thing you asked I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can adjust the execution speed of any SKAction with its speed property. For example, if you set action.speed = 2, the action will run twice as fast.

```
SKAction *moveAlongPath = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:60];
[_character runAction:moveAlongPath withKey:@"moveAlongPath"];
```

You can then adjust the character's speed by

```
[self changeActionSpeedTo:2 onNode:_character];
```

Method to change the speed of an SKAction...

```
- (void) changeActionSpeedTo:(CGFloat)speed onNode:(SKSpriteNode *)node
{
    SKAction *action = [node actionForKey:@"moveAlongPath"];
    if (action) {
      action.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing complicated calculations, modifying the animation duration based on the object speed and other factors. Seems a bit backwards :-) This could be doable though, if messy.

Is there any way to place a sprite on a point in a CGPath "manually"? Using SKAction is not a requirement, I can probably deal with the movement stuff myself if I could do that.

Comment: Moving a sprite along an arbitrary CGPath with constant speed is non-trivial. Determining the animation duration is relatively easy. Does the character speed up deterministically or as a result of a random event (e.g., an enemy chasing it)?

Comment: I think the approach I will take is to precalculate the duration for each CGPath such that the sprite will move at some baseline speed (which will probably require some guesswork/eyeballing), and then modify the sprite speed property to slow it down (or stop it) as necessary. Then I think I only need a single action for each path, and the sprites on that path can move at different speeds. Initial tests seem promising.

Answer (score 1):

Try some think like this :

```
CGMutablePathRef cgpath = CGPathCreateMutable();

//random values
float xStart = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0+enemy.size.width to:screenRect.size.width-enemy.size.width ];
float xEnd = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0+enemy.size.width to:screenRect.size.width-enemy.size.width ];

//ControlPoint1
float cp1X = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0+enemy.size.width to:screenRect.size.width-enemy.size.width ];
float cp1Y = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0+enemy.size.width to:screenRect.size.width-enemy.size.height ];

//ControlPoint2
float cp2X = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0+enemy.size.width to:screenRect.size.width-enemy.size.width ];
float cp2Y = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:cp1Y];

CGPoint s = CGPointMake(xStart, 1024.0);
CGPoint e = CGPointMake(xEnd, -100.0);
CGPoint cp1 = CGPointMake(cp1X, cp1Y);
CGPoint cp2 = CGPointMake(cp2X, cp2Y);
CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath,NULL, s.x, s.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, e.x, e.y);

SKAction *planeDestroy = [SKAction followPath:cgpath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];
[self addChild:enemy];

SKAction *remove2 = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[enemy runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[planeDestroy,remove2]]];

CGPathRelease(cgpath);
```

Comment: As I said above, I need to have the sprite move along the path with an arbitrarily changing velocity, which this does not seem to support.